# Flutter: Card() / Firebase - (Beginner problem)

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter. I have a problem with a small project. I collect data from a Firebase DB and adding it into a listTile. I am trying to add 2 static ListTile but they are added to the homescreen for every loop. I can't get a out of the loop - Any one there are willing to help.

The "Datablade" and "Vejledning" listtile are added for every loop

'''

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/services/database.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

//import 'package:flutter_app/screens/home/brew_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/models/brew.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<List<Brew>>.value(
      value: DatabaseService().filer,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,

        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Arbejdsmiljø'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.orange[400],
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: Text('Log ud'),
              onPressed: () async {
                await _auth.signOut();

              },
            ),
          ],

        ),

        body:


              ListPage(),

            ),


          );








      //ListPage(),



  }
}

class ListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ListPageState createState() => _ListPageState();
}

class _ListPageState extends State<ListPage> {

  Future _data;

  Future getPosts() async{

    var firestore = Firestore.instance;

    QuerySnapshot qn = await firestore.collection('filer').getDocuments();
    return qn.documents;

  }

  navigateToDetail(DocumentSnapshot post) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(post: post,)));
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _data = getPosts();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(



      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _data,
          builder: (_, snapshot){

            if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
              return Center(
                child: Text('Loading'),
              );
            } else {

              return ListView.builder(




                //return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (_, index){
                    return Card(

                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget> [
                          ListTile(
                            leading: Icon(Icons.star, color: Colors.orange, size: 26.0),
                            onTap: () => navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index]),
                            title: Text('Datablade'),
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),

                          ),
                          Divider(color: Colors.orange,indent: 16.0),


                          ListTile(
                            title: new Center(child: new Text("Vejledninger",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.orange[400],
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, fontSize: 25.0),)),

                          ),




                          ListTile(
                              onTap: () => navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index]),
                              title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["name"]),
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.orange[400],
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  child: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["name"][0])
                              )

                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );

                    //return ListTile(
                    //title: Text(snapshot.data[index].data["name"]),
                    //onTap: () => navigateToDetail(snapshot.data[index]),
                    //);


                  });

            }

          }),


    );
  }
}



class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {

  final DocumentSnapshot post;
  DetailPage ({this.post});

  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.post.data["name"]),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Card(
          child: ListTile(
            title: Text(widget.post.data["name"]),
            subtitle: Text(widget.post.data['beskrivelse']),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

'''
```

Comment: Screen shot of the problem https://prnt.sc/qhnn16

Comment: you have hardcoded values `Text('Datablade)` and  `Text("Vejledninger",)`in your builder. When you iterate the documents these values are populating your list. You can just remove them from the builder and put them in a row/col before your builder

Comment: Yes know that the the problem - But it is like no matter where I write it, it do not work. My best guess is here https://prnt.sc/qhsw8d but then the ListPage() are not drawn to the page